# Why store result set when determing the number of rows returned in PHP prepared statement for select query?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

So after struggling for quiet some time I came across the solution that I need to use store_result() function to transfer the rows returned(from select query) to I don't know where, but it seems unnecessary and even costly to first transfer the results and then checking number of rows.

eg..

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM login_info WHERE user_id=? AND password=?";

        //Prepare statement
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

        //bind parameters to prepared statement
        $stmt->bind_param("ss",$userId,$password);

        //execute query
        $stmt->execute();

        //fetch number of rows returned
        echo $count = $stmt->num_rows;
```

$count value is 0. But after adding $stmt->store_result(); to the above code it works.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM login_info WHERE user_id=? AND password=?";

        //Prepare statement
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

        //bind parameters to prepared statement
        $stmt->bind_param("ss",$userId,$password);

        //execute query
        $stmt->execute();

        //store result  
        $stmt->store_result();

        //fetch number of rows returned
        echo $count = $stmt->num_rows;
```

Now code prints the number of rows as 1 in count variable.

Comment: Refer to a manual please. Here's a link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.store-result.php

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to ask for all rows just to get a count. If you only need the count, ask for it explicitly `SELECT COUNT(*) AS total ...`. If you actually need the rows, count while you retrieve them. In your case, why do you need a count in the first place? Do you expect to have many users with the same username and password?

Comment: @Álvaro González No but this is how I am trained to do, check that count is greater than 0 and obviously count will always be 1.

Comment: Well your trainers are wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because prepared queries are [unbuffered](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.buffering.php) by default. And num_rows is unavailable for unbuffered queries.

Let me also observe that the number of rows returned by the query is essentially useless. Every time you think you need it, you may find that you already have the information you need. Not to mention that this number if often even being misused, doing some serious harm to the server. So there is little to no use for the num_rows at all.

For example, in your case, obviously you don't need the *number* of rows returned, but just a *flag, whether your query returned anything or not.* So you've got plenty of such flags already. the result of `fetch()` for example or the fetched data itself.

Comment: Sorry I am afraid I don't follow can you tell further why is it so.

Comment: I just updated my answer. Anyway, being a noob, you ought to quit mysqli and start PDO.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Are row counts really useless though? How would you paginate results without retrieving a row count? Is there any other way? Just curious...